# Assigning Same Colors For Same Variables in Two Different Data Set for plotting in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 data sets. One has 17 variables while the other has 10. They have overlapping variables. I draw barplots for each data set but the colors for the same variable is different.

Is there a way to assign color for each variable that I can use in both of the plots?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just specify the colors manually (look into ` ?ggplot2::scale_color_manual`). Also, if you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) you can help others to help you!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could do this easily by assigning color = variable

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(n, color = variable)) + 
    geom_bar()
```

Need to ensure that your df is in a tidy format first.